# Jetpack Compose - DataStore/Flows problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I can't understand why content of `collect` function in `SplashViewModel` is executed after "Finish" button click.

Of course content is called when app starts, because `SplashViewModel` is injected in the `MainActivity` and the 'init' function from 'SplashViewModel' is called but i don't know why app is moving me to `AUTH` graph after clicking `Finish` button...

This is the part of code which i mean when im using a 'content' word:

```
val route =
                        if (completed == true) NavigationDestinations.Auth.GRAPH else NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH
                    splashEventChannel.send(BaseUiEvent.Navigate(route))

                    _isLoading.value = false
```

It looks like when 'saveOnBoardingState' function from 'OnBoardingViewModel' is executed then is re-emitted last flow value in `SplashViewModel` or something?

Here is my code:

'DataStoreManager' File

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("user_preferences")

class DataStoreManager(context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    fun <T> getValueFromDataStore(preferencesKey: Preferences.Key<T>) =
        dataStore.data.catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }.map {
            val value = it[preferencesKey]
            value
        }


    suspend fun <T> storeValue(key: Preferences.Key<T>, value: T) =
        dataStore.edit { it[key] = value }

}
```

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) :
    ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow();

    private val splashEventChannel = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val splashScreenEvents = splashEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStoreManager.getValueFromDataStore(PreferenceKey.onBoardingCompleted)
                .collect { completed ->
                    val route =
                        if (completed == true) NavigationDestinations.Auth.GRAPH else NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH
                    splashEventChannel.send(BaseUiEvent.Navigate(route))

                    _isLoading.value = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen().apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                splashViewModel.isLoading.value
            }
        }

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

                LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                    splashViewModel.splashScreenEvents.collect { event ->
                        when (event) {
                            is BaseUiEvent.Navigate -> {
//                                navController.popBackStack()
                                navController.navigate(event.route)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    content = { innerPadding ->
                        Surface(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(innerPadding)
                        ) {
                            SetupNavGraph(
                                navController = navController,
                                scaffoldState = scaffoldState
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen(
//    navController: NavHostController,
    onBoardingViewModel: OnBoardingViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val pages = listOf(
        OnBoardingPage.OnBoardingWelcomePage,
        OnBoardingPage.OnBoardingSecondPage,
        OnBoardingPage.OnBoardingLastPage
    )

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            count = pages.count(),
            state = pagerState,
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            ) {
                OnBoardingScreenPage(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 200.dp),
                    onBoardingPage = pages[page]
                )
            }
        }

        Indicators(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 80.dp),
            size = pages.size,
            index = pagerState.currentPage
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(48.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = pagerState.currentPage != pagerState.pageCount - 1,
                enter = slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { -it }).plus(fadeIn()),
                exit = slideOutHorizontally(targetOffsetX = { -it }).plus(fadeOut())
            ) {
                TextButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pages.size - 1)
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.skip))
                }
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
                visible = pagerState.currentPage != pagerState.pageCount - 1,
                enter = slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { it }).plus(fadeIn()),
                exit = slideOutHorizontally(targetOffsetX = { it }).plus(fadeOut())
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(end = 16.dp),
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    onClick = {
                        if (pagerState.currentPage + 1 < pages.size)
                            scope.launch {
                                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                            }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.next)
                    )

                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowForward,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                visible = pagerState.currentPage == pagerState.pageCount - 1,
                enter = expandHorizontally(expandFrom = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) { 0 }.plus(
                    fadeIn()
                ),
                exit = shrinkHorizontally(shrinkTowards = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) { 0 }.plus(
                    fadeOut()
                ),
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 32.dp),
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    onClick = {
                        onBoardingViewModel.saveOnBoardingState(true)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Finish")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class OnBoardingViewModel @Inject constructor(private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) :
    ViewModel() {

    fun saveOnBoardingState(completed: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStoreManager.storeValue(key = PreferenceKey.onBoardingCompleted, value = completed)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to the screen not to change after clicking the `Finish` button and content of `collect` function not been executed more than one time.

Please help me because i can't solve this problem for few days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

The screen was changing after clicking `Finish` button, because the flow in `SplashViewModel` never stopped collecting values. Whenever i changed "onBoardingCompleted"(Boolean) value in Data Store by calling `saveOnBoardingState` function then that value was automatically emitted.

To fix that we have to use `.first()` flow operator which collecting only first emitted value and cancels the flow instead of `.collect()` operator.

Old code:

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) :
    ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow();

    private val splashEventChannel = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val splashScreenEvents = splashEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataStoreManager.getValueFromDataStore(PreferenceKey.onBoardingCompleted)
                .collect { completed ->
                    val route =
                        if (completed == true) NavigationDestinations.Auth.GRAPH else NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH
                    splashEventChannel.send(BaseUiEvent.Navigate(route))

                    _isLoading.value = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Working code:

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) :
    ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow();

    private val splashEventChannel = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val splashScreenEvents = splashEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val onBoardingCompleted =
                dataStoreManager.getValueFromDataStore(PreferenceKey.onBoardingCompleted, false)
                    .first()

            val route =
                if (onBoardingCompleted) NavigationDestinations.Auth.GRAPH else NavigationDestinations.OnBoarding.GRAPH
            splashEventChannel.send(BaseUiEvent.Navigate(route))

            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

btw i have improved a `getValueFromDataStore` function in a `DataStoreManager`. Here is the code:

```
    fun <T> getValueFromDataStore(preferencesKey: Preferences.Key<T>, default: T): Flow<T> {
        return dataStore.data.catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }.map {
            it[preferencesKey] ?: default
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide github link of you project

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, this is my private project

Comment: okay not un issue can you please share recourse that help you in that